# Do weaker/less specific types in Java affect performance?

Tags: java

Consider the following bits of Java code:

```
for(ArrayList<String> str : strList) {
    // something
}

for(Iterable<String> str : strList) {
    // something
}
```

Depending on what happens inside the loop, it may well not be necessary to use ArrayList or List, but we can instead of Iterable.

Does this have a performance benefit or is it purely a conceptual thing where you define it to tell the reader of the code that this is all you'll ever be doing with the object?

Comment: No performance benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's purely conceptual. The language construct you're utilizing there *requires* the `str` object to implement the `Iterable` interface. Even if you pass an `ArrayList` (or subclass thereof), it's going to treat it as an `Iterable`

Comment: Thanks for confirming